# Keras Updating loss value inside optimizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am building an optimizer (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py) which calculates a search direction and then tries a few different step lengths to find which gives the lowest loss. However, I am running into problems when trying to change the step length depending on the value of the loss itself. It appears that the loss (which is a tensor dependant upon the weight of the network and the data) cannot be updated/recalculated more than once during each training loop, which I find very odd.

This is the relevant code I have in *get_updates(self, loss, params):*

```
    L1 = loss

    for p, direction in zip(params, directions):
        self.updates.append(K.update(p, p+length*direction))

    L2 = loss

    for p, direction in zip(params, directions):
        self.updates.append(K.update(p, tf.cond( L2<L1, lambda: p+0.5*length*direction, lambda: p))
```

The problem is that L1 and L2 are the same and no matter what I try I can't get the loss to update after I've updated the weights. I've also tried just p = p+length*direction and p.assign() but the loss doesn't update. Does anyone know how I can get an updated value of the loss?
Note, I am able to get the loss from the previous batch/epoch if I save a loss value and update using self.updates.append(K.update(self.prev_loss,loss)), however since the data will change between batches I am no longer working on the same loss function and thus my comparison between the losses to determine if the step length should be lower is not valid.

Comment: Regarding this, "The problem is that L1 and L2 are the same and no matter what I try":
Where is loss being updated? It looks to me like you are assigning L1 and L2 to the same variable, so you get the same value

Comment: Additionally, is loss a python variable or a tensorflow variable?

Comment: loss is the input to the function, which is a tensor containing all the operations and such (so that you can calculate the gradients). The loss itself is not "updated" inside the optimizer that I can see (if you look though the link to the Keras optimizers for example), from my understanding it is being run from the model each epoch/training update.

Comment: It might be that I'm simply just "creating the same reference to the loss for both L1 and L2", but I can't figure out how not to do this :S The loss is dependent upon what's is changing inside the for loops, so the loops should have some effect.

Comment: I think you can try a simple test to see where loss is changing. If you print L1 before and after the loop what does it give you?

If loss is a tensorflow variable then L1 and L2 will be referring to the same thing

Comment: It is the same before/after the loop, it is the same everywhere in the get_updates function (Note, this function is only called once to build a list of updates which are later called to run the tensorflow graphs). It appears to only changes between training steps, in other words once the list of updates has been performed :/

Comment: I think you need to provide some more code so we have some context around this

Comment: The code on github (the link in the post) is very similar, in fact, the code I posted is basically all the code you need in the get_updates function to make it run (except for the code calculating the direction, though that is completely unrelated to this problem).

Comment: From the code you have shown me, I don't see why you expect the loss to change. You aren't changing the value of the variable anywhere. The loss does not change when you run the optimizer. Loss is a measure of how well the model behaves over an iteration. If your optimizer sets new weights for the model, you need to run again to get a new loss that corresponds to the updated weights

Comment: The reason I thought it would change is because params is linked to loss, thus when I update the values of the params (weights) I thought the loss would change too. So the question really becomes how do I get the new loss after I have updated the weights (which are updated in the for loop).

Comment: You need to compute the loss to update the weights, then with new weights you need to compute the loss again. How are you getting the loss at the moment?

Comment: The loss function is created when I make the neural network model, in the optimizer I use the loss which is given as input to calculate the gradient w.r.t params and then I update the params. The problem seems to be that the weights in the loss function do not update when I update params :/ I cannot eval the loss since get_update only builds a list of operations so I don’t know how to update the loss without going to the next itteration :s

Comment: The *loss* here is the same as *total_loss* in the (in my case Sequential) Model.

Comment: @Behzad I think I've found the problem, I've added a new question which is more general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61520412/how-do-i-change-the-output-from-a-tensor-by-updating-a-variable