# How do I change the output from a tensor by updating a variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a loss function which is dependant on some variable, then I want to change that variable and get the updated loss. The loss is given to me as an input to a function, so I can't simply move that line under  **tf.control_dependencies** (which does give me what I want). So how do I go about updating the variable and loss afterwards?

```
X = tf.Variable(1.0)                     #Dummy parameters of a neural network
loss = (X+1.0)**2                        #Dummy Loss function given to me as input

add = tf.assign(X,X+1.0)                 #Me changing the parameters of the network
with tf.control_dependencies( [ add ] ):
    updated_loss = loss                  #Me wanting the updated loss
print(K.eval(updated_loss ))             #Me not getting the updated loss :(
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make the loss variable, you are giving it an initial value, this doesn't make it a function that will reevaluate the loss every time it is called.

We can make a loss function that is called to calculate the loss each time

Edit:
I changed the code below to reassign a value to the loss tensorflow variable rather than returning a new variable.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

# Function that updates the loss
@tf.function
def update_loss(X, loss):
    loss.assign((X+1.0)**2)

def test():
    # Initialise a value of loss
    loss = tf.Variable(0.0)
    print(K.eval(loss))

    # Initialise variable
    X = tf.Variable(2.0)

    # Update loss
    update_loss(X, loss)
    print(K.eval(loss))

    # Change network by adding 1.0
    X.assign_add(1.0)

    # Update loss
    update_loss(X, loss)
    print(K.eval(loss))
```

Comment: This is what I want to do, the problem is that I'm not defining **loss** myself as in this dummy example, I have the loss as a Tensor and I need some way of getting the new value after I update the X variable without redefining the whole loss function.

Comment: Alternatively, if there's some way to copy all the operations from the loss tensor to build a loss function from the operations in the loss tensor that would work too, but when I tried doing that things seemed to get tangled up and not actually a copy :/ Another problem which might cause more issues is that my real loss tensor also depends on some placeholders, which could make using it as a function more cumbersome.

Comment: A tensor cannot contain a reference to another variable. So you will have to evaluate the loss function at some point.
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tensor

Is there a reason why you want to represent the loss as a tensor?

Comment: Yes, I am modifying a function in Keras which gets the loss as an input, so I only have access to that tensor (and the parameters of the network referenced by the loss tensor).

Comment: You want to change the loss inside the function, which then persists outside the function?

Comment: Yes, well, the function itself is only called once to build the computation graph which is later evaluated to update the parameters. However I want this graph to update the value of the parameters based on the value of the loss tensor with different parameter values.

Comment: What I don't quite understand is why the loss tensor does not update its value. If I modify my dummy code to **updated_loss  = loss + X** the X value is the updated (2) value, but the loss which should be a reference to X is still 4 (X=1)

Comment: Because loss is a tensor, it can't store a reference to X. It only stores the value of X when it is initialised. If you print loss, you will see something like tf.Tensor(2.0, shape=(), dtype=float32). A tensor cannot have dtype=tf.Variable

Comment: Aaahh.. okay, but how do I tell tensorflow I want the updated value of the loss? If I run **K.eval(loss)** I do get the updated value of the loss (for X=2). I can't run the session to get the updated loss, since I want to create the graph which should later be ran, so is there some method I can use to tell tensorflow to refresh the value of **X** in **loss** when making the **updated_loss** ?  (This is what I thought **tf.control_dependencies** did)

Comment: I have made an edit to the code so it assigns a new value to loss so the change will persist outside the function

Comment: The problem is that I do not have the loss function like I have in this dummy example, loss = (X+1)^2, but I only have the loss tensor. The loss is built up by Keras to be the whole complex neural network loss, so I don't want to rebuild that whole thing (for practical and performance reasons), but rather be able to get the value of the loss tensor with updated parameters, same as I get when I do run K.eval(loss), but I need to get that value when building the **updated_loss**

Comment: If the type is tf.Tensor then you cannot update it since a tensor is immutable

Comment: I think you have contradicting requirements. You can't ask for X and loss to be both dependent on each other and independent from one another

Comment: Is there any simple way to make a "copy" if the loss tensor operations so that I can evaluate it using a function? :/ Might be the only solution here :S